# sqljdbc4 2 on Glassfish server4 1

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, glassfish, sqljdbc

I am running my java web application on `glassfish server v4.1` in `netbeans v8.0.2`, using `sqljdbc42` and this connection code-

```
    Connection connection;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Lista;integratedSecurity=true";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

When i open my ide and run my project for the first time the glassfish server starts automatically since my project's server is glassfish, and i can perform any crud operation with my `Ms-Sql server2012`.

But the problem starts when i make changes in any file keeping the server on and run the project again and try to perform any crud operation i get this following error-

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
>   configured for integrated authentication

But if i stop the server before changing any file and start after changing and run the project then it works without any error.

Stopping and re-starting the server again and again taking so many times from my total project time! Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!

The error (described in my question above) i was getting because the glassfish server had not any access on `sqljdbc42.jar` file. so i have placed the `sqljdbc42.jar` file into my glassfish server in this location-

`glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib`.

And it's now working perfectly.

Thank you everyone!